# Find $f(4)$ where $f$ is a polynomial such that $f'(x)+f(x)=x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> $f(x)$ is polynomial function
>
> and
>   $$f'(x)+f(x)=x,$$ 
>   then what is the value of $f(4)=$?
>
> **The Answer**  is $f(4)=3$
>    , but I don't know how?

Comment: i have edited ... check now

Comment: Fine, now it is correct. Did you read the answers below?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint. Let $f$ be a polynomial function of degree $n\geq 1$, then the degree of the polynomial $f'$ is $n-1$ and the degree of the sum $f+f'$ is still equal to $n$. Since $f'(x)+f(x)=x$, it follows that $n=1$ and $f(x)=ax+b$ for some constants $a$ and $b$. Hence
$$f'(x)+f(x)=a+ax+b=ax+(a+b)=x\Rightarrow \begin{cases}a=1\\a+b=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: but why a = 1 ? or  a+b =0

Comment: Two polynomials are identical if they have the same coefficients.

Comment: Two polynomials > do you mean f(x) + f'(x)

Comment: No, I mean $ax+(a+b)$ and $x$.

Comment: okay so , from where  we deduce this $$ax+(a+b)$$

Comment: It is $f'(x)+f(x)$ with $f(x)=ax+b$.

Comment: $$ax+b$$ general formula of  polynomial function from first degree ? right

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 4):

What you have is called an ***Ordinary Differential Equation*** which can be solved by implementing a little trick that involves multiplying both sides by $e^x$ :

$$f'(x) + f(x) = x \Rightarrow e^xf'(x) + e^xf(x) = xe^x$$

Now, one can easily see that the RHS is :

$$e^xf'(x) + e^xf(x) = [e^xf(x)]'$$

That means that you will now have :

$$[e^xf(x)]'= xe^x \Rightarrow \int[e^xf(x)]'dx=\int xe^xdx \Rightarrow e^xf(x)= e^x(x-1)+c_1 $$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$f(x) = (x-1) + c_1e^{-x}$$

Now, just find $f(2)$ to find that its value is, that it will be an expression involving the constant $c_1$. **But** be careful : since you need $f$ to be a polynomial, then the exponential factor should be diminished. That means that $c_1 = 0$, which leads to :

$$f(x) = x-1 \Rightarrow f(2) = 2-1=1$$

**Note :** As mentioned in the comments, please either check the exercise or the answer, since the answer for the particular problem **is wrong**.

Comment: he asked for polynomial!!

Comment: @Holo So ? That just means that $c_1 = 0$.

Comment: when someone ask a differential equation about polynomials they are probably asking for a way to solve this using polynomials(system of equations), and not using integrals

Comment: @Rebellos this is the answer $$f(x) = x-1 \Rightarrow f(2) = 2-1=1$$
but why we use integration?

Comment: @johnwick It's a common way to solve such differential equations.

Comment: @Holo No solution restriction was mentioned and when a person is into calculus, why not demonstrate the most common way of presenting a solution to such a problem ?

Comment: @Rebellos because questions are created to give us a way to study, when people study this material this is usually still at the start of differential equation, so it is better to understand thing by the way they study them.

Comment: @Holo This is a starter's differential equation and I'm pretty sure if one studies it this way, he'll understand that he can manipulate his expressions into being easy antiderivatives by multiplying by exponentials.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$xe^x=\dfrac{d\{e^xf(x)\}}{dx}$$

Integrating both sides
$$e^xf(x)=\int xe^x\ dx$$

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html

Comment: OP asked for polynomial

Comment: Nevertheless, the general solution of this differential equation is $f(x)=Ce^{-x}+x-1$, whence we get our polynomial for $C=0$. Of course, such method is not natural in this context, but it throws some light for certain general aspect.

Comment: @szw1710 when someone ask a differential equation about polynomials they are probably asking for a way to solve this using polynomials(system of equations), and not using integrals

Comment: @Holo I wanted to point out the hidden beauty of a problem. This is not a suggestion how to solve this exercise, the solution given by Robert Z is nice and adequate to the problem in question. However, sometimes it is nice to observe more general things.